# Python 3, beginner errors

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I have to input the class name, faculty name, name/letter grade of every student. Write the info to a file, then displace the amount of each grade. I'm Getting errors on lines 19, 55, and 41. Line 19 gives an error type 'str' object is not callable. Can anyone help? Here's what I have:

```
Grades = open("ClassNameGrades.txt", "w")

count = 0
A=0
B=0
C=0
D=0
F=0

def gradeInput(count,numStudents,A,B,C,D,F):
    while count<numStudents:
        studentName=input("Enter name of student - ")
        Grades.write(studentName("\n"))       <<<Error#1
        studentGrade=input("Enter student letter grade - ", ).upper()
        Grades.write(studentGrade("\n"))
        count=count+1
        if studentGrade =="A":
            A+=1
        elif studentGrade =="B":
            B+=1
        elif studentGrade =="C":
            C+=1
        elif studentGrade =="D":
            D+=1
        elif studentGrade =="F":
            F+=1
    return count,numStudents,A,B,C,D,F

def main():
    Grades.write=input("Enter name of class - ",)
    Grades.write= input("Enter name of faculty - ")
    numStudents =int(float(input("Enter the amount of students - ")))
    gradeInput(count,numStudents,A,B,C,D,F)    <<Error#2
    print("Students who got an A = ", A)
    print("Students who got an B = ", B)
    print("Students who got an C = ", C)
    print("Students who got an D = ", D)
    print("Students who got an F = ", F)

main()   <<Error#3

Grades.close()
```

Comment: I guess you want `Grades.write(studentName + "\n")`

Comment: Nope, same error.

Comment: It's strange that writing the name of the student is a problem, but writing the grade is fine.

Comment: `studentName("\n")` ... that is a function call but studentName is a string, not a function. You can append newlines with `studentName + "\n"` or perhap `"{}\n".format(studentName)`.

Comment: `gradeInput(count,numStudents,A,B,C,D,F)    <<Error#2` ... this function returns its new values but you don't remember. The integers in A, B, etc... were not changed. `gradInput` only changed its local copy of those variables.

Answer (score 0):

For the first: Instead of `Grades.write(studentGrade("\n"))`, it would be `Grades.write(studentGrade + "\n")`.

The former is a function call, but you're feeding that to a string.

The latter merges the two strings, so if the student grade was "A", it would write "A\n", which is A, then a newline.